# Python, loops return same index twice

Tags: python

Why does this function return the index as 3 two times, instead of 3 and 4 ?

```
def commands(binary_str):
    dict = {4: "wink",
            3: "double blink",
            2: "close your eyes",
            1: "jump"}
    z=[]
    y = list(binary_str)
    for i in y:
        if int(i) == 1:
            print(y.index(i))
            z.append(dict[y.index(i)])
        
    return z

print(commands("00011"))
```

Comment: You do `y.index(1)` twice, that gives 3, why would you expect it to have 3 and 4 ?

Comment: You give two 1, that result in two 3, that very logic, same input, same output

Comment: `index` gives you the first index where respective element occurs - which is 3 in the example.

Comment: thanks, that was dumb.

Comment: you could use e.g. a list comprehension to get all indices of a certain value; `[i for i, v in enumerate("00011") if int(v) == 1]`

Comment: @MrFuppes or `[i for i, v in enumerate("00011") if v == '1']`